# Whats the best way to handle changes to settings (iPhone/iPad)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, settings

I have just been implementing the InAppSettingsKit for my app and now I'm trying to determine the best way to push out the new settings to my app. At present I have a couple of different view controllers that will be effected by setting changes. I understand that I will need to use a delegate method, however I would like some advice on how best to update other view controllers with new settings. Is there some sort of best practice that should be followed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that inAppSettingsKit uses `NSUserDefaults`, in which case the same practices apply.

General good practice for changed settings is to observe the notification `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` and update your views in the observer method.  As many observers are usually required, delegate methods aren't a good solution for this problem.